# Python with SFTP library fails with correct code

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
import pysftp

cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None   

host = "192.168.8.104"
username = "pi"
password = "raspberry"

local_path = "C:\Users\helencecilia\Desktop\Basura\Conexion SFTP\download.txt" 
remote_path = "\home\pi\helloworld.txt"

with pysftp.Connection(host, username, password, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    sftp.put(local_path, remote_path)
```

Error message:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py:61: UserWarning: Failed to load HostKeys from C:\Users\helencecilia\.ssh\known_hosts.  You will need to explicitly load HostKeys (cnopts.hostkeys.load(filename)) or disableHostKey checking (cnopts.hostkeys = None).
  warnings.warn(wmsg, UserWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\helencecilia\Desktop\Basura\Conexion SFTP\prueba.py", line 12, in <module>
    with pysftp.Connection(host, username, password, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 142, in __init__
    self._set_authentication(password, private_key, private_key_pass)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 167, in _set_authentication
    private_key_file, private_key_pass)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\pkey.py", line 196, in from_private_key_file
    key = cls(filename=filename, password=password)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\rsakey.py", line 45, in __init__
    self._from_private_key_file(filename, password)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\rsakey.py", line 163, in _from_private_key_file
    data = self._read_private_key_file('RSA', filename, password)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\pkey.py", line 267, in _read_private_key_file
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'raspberry'
```

- The ip address is correct
- The name and password is correct
- The ssh server is connected correctly and they are the same network
- Desk paths are correct and exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument must be `private_key`, not `password` according to the [API documentation](https://pysftp.readthedocs.io/en/release_0.2.9/pysftp.html#pysftp.Connection):

> class pysftp.Connection(host, username=None, private_key=None, password=None, port=22, private_key_pass=None, ciphers=None, log=False, cnopts=None, default_path=None)

Either pass `None` for the `private_key` argument:

```
pysftp.Connection(host, username, None, password, cnopts=cnopts)
```

or better, use keyword arguments:

```
pysftp.Connection(host=host, username=username, password=password, cnopts=cnopts)
```